# Cordova Xcode environment variable

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I would like to check if it is possible for my mobile app built by Cordova to access to the Xcode Environment variable? As I would like to switch between different backend and use the Xcode environment variable to help me with it.(different built schemes can have different backend URL).
https://m25lazi.medium.com/environment-variables-in-xcode-a78e07d223ed
I would like to use this in my Cordova application
Thank you